# Get names of devices connected to Bluetooth HC-06 and Arduino

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, device

We are getting started with Arduino and we had some doubts. We want to connect the Arduino and the Bluetooth (we already have the connection done) so we can move a servo motor with an Android app.

The problem is that we want to know the devices connected to the Bluetooth and make a control of them, we will send that list to the computer. We are using a Bluetooth HC-06, so is there a way or any command to know which devices are connected to that Bluetooth? We were discussing that maybe we will need to change to a Bluetooth HC-05 but we want to try first with this one.

Answer (score 0):

The HC-06 is a slave only so other devices can not connect to it and so there can not be any list with devices connected. A slave can only connected to one master device. The HC-06 does not allow any queries about its connection state as far as I am aware.

The HC-05 can do master or slave operations. This is the module you need to do what you describe.